# How to use TYPO3 log channel attribute

Tags: logging, typo3, typo3-11.x

What are [TYPO3 log channels](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Logging/Logger/Index.html#channels) for?
I hoped to use them as a convenient new way to pool log messages for a specific channel/logfile. But either I am missing how to configure that or this is not what the channel attribute is intended for…

**Edit:** I am of course using php 8.

Comment: Did you pay attention to "This feature is only available with PHP 8. The channel attribute will be gracefully ignored in PHP 7 (...)"?

Comment: Perhaps i should have clarified that i am of course using php 8. I updated the question accordingly. However, the fact still remains that nowhere in the docs is a clarification WHAT the grouping by channel attribute can exactly be used for.

Comment: The main use in the core seems to be the categorization of the syslog entries. But I agree, the documentation on the feature is sparse.

Comment: Tamali and @Julian I created an issue for the documentation. I will work on updating it tomorrow. Please check out my answer and leave feedback if something is missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Services are now able to control the component name that an injected logger is created with.

From the change https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/commit/8e0cdb4646118734d48c184bcca63ef17ada8ad2

I think the relevant part here is "component name". When a [Logger](https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/main/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Log/Logger.php) is created, a name is set. Usually, this is constructed from the namespace of the class. For example if we have the class `TYPO3\CMS\Linkvalidator\LinkAnalyzer`, the name is 'TYPO3.CMS.Linkvalidator.LinkAnalyzer'. This can then be used as `['TYPO3']['CMS']['Linkvalidator']['LinkAnalyzer']` when configuring the logging.

With the channel we can replace this mechanism and set an arbitrary name and thus use this for several related classes, regardless of the namespace or class name.

Long story short, for channel name "linkvalidator" configure like this:

---

**LinkAnalyzer.php:**

```
namespace TYPO3\CMS\Linkvalidator;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Log\Channel;
#[Channel('linkvalidator')]

// Add this to the constructor
public function __construct(
        // ....
        protected readonly LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger->debug('Linkvalidator constructur');
        // ...
    }
```

**AdditionalConfiguration.php:**

*(use **system/additional.php** in v12 and above)*

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Environment;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Log\LogLevel;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Log\Writer\FileWriter;



$logdir = Environment::getVarPath() . '/log/';

// without channel
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['LOG']['TYPO3']['CMS']['Linkvalidator']['LinkAnalyzer']['writerConfiguration'] = [
    LogLevel::DEBUG => [
        FileWriter::class => [
            'logFile' => $logdir . 'typo3-linkvalidator.log'
        ]
    ],
];


// with channel
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['LOG']['linkvalidator']['writerConfiguration'] = [
    LogLevel::DEBUG => [
        FileWriter::class => [
            'logFile' => $logdir . 'typo3-linkvalidator-CHANNEL.log'
        ]
    ],
];
```

With channel, the file `typo3-linkvalidator-CHANNEL.log` is written. Directory depends:

- with Composer: `var/log`
- without Composer: `typo3temp/var/log`